# Returning completely different data types from a function

Tags: c++, return, return-type

I'm trying to translate the codebase for my programming language from Lua to C++. I've just started. I'm not a C++ expert, and I hope I can learn more *while* writing it, but I already encountered an obstacle which made me stop.

I am now writing the lexical analyzer module. It is supposed to return a doubly linked list of tokens, but of course, error can occour while analyzing the source code, e.g. when a multi line comment or string has no ending bracket and things like that.

I could of course, when I encounter an error, print the message and just end the program. But since I want to make those errors handable, the easiest thing I can think of is to *return* these errors, so that if an error handling function gets that error, it can, well, handle it, but if it gets all the way down to the interpreter, its message is then printed.

In Lua, it was easy. I could make a function return either a doubly linked list of tokens (I used sizeless arrays there, but that's unimportant) if the lexical analyzer function encountered no errors in the passed text, or an error object to be handled by the caller.

Since C++ has to specify a return type however, how can I make a function return an error object if necessary so that it can be handled correctly? Or should I change approach and use something else than the return system?

Unfortunately I'm not able to search the huge codebase of languages like Python to look at how they handle this situation, so even a link to those files could help.

Comment: Inheritance - base class `Error` carries a message and a location - the console/logging part should behappy with that. From `Error` derive your specific classes to carry info required by your 'recovery code' to do its job. Ah, and return those errors as `std::shared_ptr`. For the actual return of your token list, return them in a function parameter (pointer/reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is just for the error handling, you might probably want to use [exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error), because that is the standard error handling mechanism in C++. Of course, you would have to catch and handle these exceptions somewhere, because otherwise the C++ program stops to run.

If you really need a way to get several possible return types out of a single function, you could try [unions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). This approach has the disadvantage that you need a way to indicate to the caller of you function which type you actually returned and the caller needs to check for the various possibilities.

Apart from that I can give you a general piece of advice: While I do not know your motivation for translating the codebase from Lua to C++, I would not advice to do it just for the sake of having all that code available in C++, as long as the Lua code works for your purpose. You will very likely encounter more such situations where you cannot adequately translate a language feature from Lua to C++.

Instead you could try to use Lua directly from C++ with a wrapper like the [Lua API++ library](https://github.com/OldFisher/lua-api-pp), if you need a way to interact with Lua from a C++ application.

Comment: You mean C++ exceptions for my language exceptions? That looks usable, and I surely didn't think about it. As for the Lua to C++, it's for portability, performance, and even because I can't find the source of some bugs with Lua's dinamicity.

Comment: Other than that, I don't quite understand what you mean with the unions part. How could one use those?

Comment: Yes, I mean C++ exceptions. As for portability: Lua is an interpreted language and already is quite portable, in my opinion, but your milage may vary. Performance might by a problem with Lua, but as always with performance: benchmark / measure it. You might sometimes get results you weren't expecting. And I've just added a line about the Lua API++ library, a wrapper around Lua for C++. There might also be other kinds of language bindings between Lua and C++ which allow you to (re-)use Lua from C++. Might be worth checking.

Comment: Well TBH C++ exceptions are already saving me from a lot of boilerplate code: in Lua, when I called, say, `parseExpression` from another `parseExpression`, I had to check if it returned the representation of an expression or an error object, and return it in the latter case. But in C++ they automatically return until they encounter a try / catch block, so yay. Accepting you answer

Answer (score 1):

Have the lexical analyser return an object which encapsulates the result and a flag to indicate success or failure, e.g.

```
struct Result {
  bool isValid; //flag to indicate of the result is valid

  //result from the analyzer
  std::list<int> list; 
};
```

Then inside the lexical analyzer set the flag appropriately, e.g. when an exception is thrown set isValid to false.

```
Result DoWork() {

  Result result;
  try {
    /*do real work*/

    result.list.push_back(42);
    result.isValid = true;
  }
  catch (...) {
    result.isValid = false;
  }

  return result;

}

int main() {

  Result result = DoWork();

  if (result.isValid) {
  ...
  } else {
  ...
  }


}
```

Comment: I already tought about that. I should elaborate more on the struct to carry a message and other informations, anyway is this in any way better than what Striezel suggested (I mean C++ exceptions)?

Comment: Is more OOP. Using the struct (or class) with a flag (and possibly a message or even the exception) together with the actual data, will make it obivous to users of the function (DoWork) how to interpret the meaning of the result. This will allow clients to decide how to handle the case when isValid is false. Alternatively you could just thrown an exception and force clients to handle that exception.